# string matching of synoymns in different columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk

I have a dataset which looks like this

```
  name      col1            col2                      col13 
  company1  Banking         Finance                   B&F
  company2  Utilities       Utilities                 NaN
  company3  Transportation  Pipeline Transportation   Utilities
  company4  Consulting      Tech                      Insurance
```

etc.........

So what I need to do is compare each column with each other and flag those ones which are not at all similar ( or synonymous) to each other. For example - company 4 has nothing similar so , I want to flag that. company 3 looks somewhat similar so I want to flag that as almost similar(yellow flag) and the green which are a match is green.

```
The output somewhat needs to look like this :
  name      col1            col2                      col13       flag 
  company1  Banking         Finance                   B&F          green
  company2  Utilities       Utilities                 NaN          green
  company3  Transportation  Pipeline Transportation   Utilities   yellow
  company4  Consulting      Tech                      Insurance    red
```

I know this seems kinda of a very big question , but can someone provide me a start -like how to approach this. What string matching algorithms can i use here?

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking to compare across columns only on the same rows?

Comment: yes i am looking for that

Comment: Check out the `fuzzywuzzy` module

Comment: I guess this is sort of what you're trying to figure out in your question, but it would definitely help you receive an answer much more quickly if you could explicitly define what sort of similarities you are looking for

Comment: I am looking for synonymous similarities - like banking and finance are kind of synonymous , but  finance and tech are no way close.

Comment: There is a *huge* difference in comparing `Utilities` and `Utilities` (i.e. same words) and saying they're similar, and `Banking` and `Finance`. The former can be done with a couple of lines of code; the latter can get veeeeery complex

Comment: What you can do is create some bags of similar words beforehand and check whether values in a row are/arent in those bags. But that is just no scalable for big `dfs`. May also wanna see: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12872/how-can-i-get-a-measure-of-the-semantic-similarity-of-words

Comment: Thanks for the replies. How can I use fuzzy-wuzzy between 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you can use `ratio` or `partial_ratio` from [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy#usage) to get the string similarity between cells of the same row. Next, you can also compare whether each cell of the same row are synonyms of each other by using a lexical database like [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation) (`nltk`). The caveat is that the suggested synonyms for each word is exhaustive and may not be all-encompassing - we can see this when we use WordNet but `Banking`, `Finance` and `B&F` are flagged as red. However, these two approaches might be useful to help you to start.

> Install dependencies first:

```
pip install nltk fuzzywuzzy
```

> Download WordNet:

```
python
>>> nltk.download('wordnet')
[nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora\wordnet.zip.
True
```

> Execute script:

```
import pandas as pd

from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df = pd.DataFrame({
'name': ['company 1', 'company 2', 'company 3', 'company 4'],
'col1': ['Banking', 'Utilities', 'Transportation', 'Consulting'],
'col2': ['Finance', 'Utilities', 'Pipeline Transportation', 'Utilities'],
'col3': ['B&F', 'NaN', 'Utilities', 'Insurance'],
})

def get_synonyms(word):
    synonym_list = []
    for synset in wn.synsets(word):
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            if not lemma.name() in synonym_list:
                synonym_list.append(lemma.name().replace('_',' '))
    return synonym_list

def check_flag(row):

    col1_data = row['col1']
    col2_data = row['col2']
    col3_data = row['col3']

    green_flag_threshold = 80

    # Get Fuzzy Ratio
    fuzz_ratio_1 = fuzz.ratio(col1_data,col2_data)
    fuzz_ratio_2 = fuzz.ratio(col2_data,col3_data)
    fuzz_ratio_3 = fuzz.ratio(col3_data,col1_data)

    if col1_data == col2_data or col2_data == col3_data or col3_data == col1_data or green_flag_threshold < (fuzz_ratio_1 or fuzz_ratio_2 or fuzz_ratio_3):
        return 'green'

    # Check synonyms using Wordnet (nltk)
    col1_syn_list = get_synonyms(col1_data)
    col2_syn_list = get_synonyms(col2_data)
    col3_syn_list = get_synonyms(col3_data)

    all_data = [col1_data, col2_data, col3_data]

    for col_data in all_data:
        for word in col_data.split():
            if word in (col1_syn_list or col2_syn_list or col3_syn_list):
                return 'yellow'

    return 'red'

df['flag'] = df.apply(check_flag, axis=1)

print(df)
```

> Results:

```
             col1                     col2       col3       name    flag
0         Banking                  Finance        B&F  company 1     red
1       Utilities                Utilities        NaN  company 2   green
2  Transportation  Pipeline Transportation  Utilities  company 3  yellow
3      Consulting                Utilities  Insurance  company 4     red

Process finished with exit code 0
```